# Python 2.7 consume the escape character and store value in a variable

Tags: python, string, printing, paramiko

I have a very strange problem, in `python 2.7`: I am using `paramiko`, and the output from a ssh command is coming out to be:

```
ABC | \x08ABCDEFG
```

As you can see there is a space character followed by backspace character(\x08). When I print the string using print function the answer is `ABC |ABCDEFG`, However I want to store this in a variable.

Things I have tried:

1. using `str(output)` : does not work string is same with backspace character
2. using `output.encode('UTF-8')` does not work.
3. `output.replace('\x08','')` : Not valid, since i want the space to be gone as well
4. `print(string, file='')` : file parameter not supported in python 2.7

Comment: `output.replace(' \x08','')` ?

Comment: You are confusing how your terminal *displays* the string with the string itself. It sounds like what you want to do is remove each backspace and the character that precedes it.

Answer (score 0):

If the string returned always contains  you could do `output.replace(' \x08', '')`. That would replace the space and the backspace. Otherwise, you could look for the index of the pipe and replace from that until you find the backspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to remove `\x08` and the space from your ouput:

```
import re
string = "ABC | \x08ABCDEFG"
result = re.sub(' \\x08', '', string, count=0, flags=0)
```

The variable `result` will contain the new string without `\x08` and without the space before `\x08`

You can check any regular expression here:

https://regex101.com/

You find more info on regular expressions in Python 2 here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html